# Symfony 4 - ClassNotFoundException Kernel

Tags: php, symfony

I'm actually upgrade my symfony 3.4 project to symfony 4.0.
After clone bundles from my gitlab repositories with composer update, I have an error :

```
ClassNotFoundException

Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel"?


in index.php (line 32)
```

Ok.... Easy... go index.php line 32... but, Kernel is load with App\Kernel, so any idea why I have this error or where I can search?

Thank you for your help.

index.php

```
use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// The check is to ensure we don't use .env in production
if (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
    (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
}

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== ($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev'))) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}


    // Request::setTrustedProxies(['0.0.0.0/0'], Request::HEADER_FORWARDED);

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev', $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== ($_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev')));

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

And in the "src" directory, I have the Kernel.php file

```
namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';
    .....
```

Comment: Guessing you still have AppBundle instead of App in your composer.json psr4 section.

Comment: No. I have the good path,  "": "src/"

Comment: And you ran composer dump-autoload?

Comment: Yes. Nothing same error.

Comment: Does bin/console work?

Comment: No, she doesn't.

Comment: So just for grins try the ever popular removal of the var/cache directory followed by bin/console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161990/discussion-between-skyd-and-cerad).

Comment: I am not entirely sure why but when I tried "": "src/" in a S4 app I got the same error.  Went back to "App\\": "src/" and all was well

Comment: Great!! That's work!! Thank you.
But it's very strange because i didn't change the composer.json. It's the composer.json from symfony-demo project... 
But, Thank you.

Comment: I think it is because under S4 there is not a src/App directory.  Just src.  As opposed to S3 where you actually had a src/AppBundle directory.  So for S4 the autoloader was looking for src/App/Kernel.php instead of src/Kernel.php

Comment: PSR4 autoload for Sym4 is `App\\": "src/"`

Comment: @skyd, I also have same issue , but I'm not clear the answer. please help me

Comment: Check your composer.json.
What do you have for psr-4 ?

Comment: I have the exact error deploying application to App Engine, works fine locally but when deployed to Google App Engine runtime php72 or php73 I get the error

    Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App". Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel"

Not PRS4 issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Symfony 4` uses the folder `App` for autoload `psr-4`. I tried to change it, but it didn't work out. Check the namespace at your `composer.json` file, in the property `autoload` and then `psr-4`.
Maybe you changed the default one.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you just accidentially removed the PSR-4 block in `composer.json` that is **always needed** for Symfony4:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```